# How do i run url command from my terminal?

Tags: macos, url, terminal, command

I have commands for example like this:

```
git clone https://example.com/mygit.git && cd mygit && npm i
```

in a file that i uploaded to an url, I want to run it from terminal, how do I run it from my terminal?

Comment: You just copy/paste it at the prompt.

Comment: i want it to be a simple single command that run multiple command for my purpose

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Linux distro or Windows?

Assuming its Linux - you need to have the file execute permission bit set ( see here for more information -> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm )

Then you need to execute the file with the path specified ie. if the script is called "myScript.sh" you would run:

```
./myScript.sh
```

or

```
/path/to/myScript.sh
```

Comment: thanks for the fast response answer, by the way I'm using mac

Comment: Mac has the same execution as Linux so the above should work

Comment: to be honest this answer is still unclear but thanks for giving me a clue for '.sh script', it give me some other information that I can google it to answer my question